# How can I search through every element in a for loop C

Tags: c, for-loop

I have an array storing process data. Each process has a start time and a some service time. From this, I can calculate how long other processes have to wait before execution. I display this data in a bar graph.
I have a for loop that goes through each process and plots it into the bar graph. For example, Process A has start time 0 and Service Time 5. Process B has start time 3 and service time 3. I have
process A that starts things off at time 0, it plots each point per second and after 5 seconds, the process halts.

Process B starts off at 3 seconds (has to wait till A finishes) then it will start executing.
The problem with this is that the graph plots each process one at a time because of the `for loop`. So in the case of process A, after 5 seconds when the process is done plotting, my graph will go back to 3 seconds when process B starts.
How can I make it so that I go through everything in the array and plot the points in real time. For example, When I get to 3 seconds, process A is still executing but also start plotting the graph for B alongside A.

I hope I explained it properly. If I didn't here's my code to plot the graph:

```
  for(int j=0;j<processCount;j++){
       int current_servTime = current_process[j].serviceTime;
       char current_process_name[11];
       int entryTime = current_process[j].entryTime;
       int waitPeriod = current_process[j+1].waitTime;
       strcpy(current_process_name, current_process[j].process_name);
       appendRow(current_process_name);
       appendBlank(j,entryTime); //blank space before process starts (first process = 0)
       if(waitPeriod!=0){
          for(int z = 0;z<waitPeriod;z++){
            sleep(1);
            //appendBar(Row, number to append, color, label, 1=dotted, 0=solid)
            appendBar(j,(z/z),"red","label",1); //dotted bar to show the process is waiting for the previous one to finish executing
          }
       }
      for (int y = 0;y<current_servTime; y++){
         sleep(1); //one second before you plot the next point
         //appendBar(Row, number to append, color, label, 1=dotted, 0=solid)
         appendBar(j,(y/y),"green"," ",0);
      }
      printf("%s entered the system at %d seconds.</n>",current_process[j].process_name,entryTime);


    }
```

Comment: The inner loops (z, y) are using z/z and y/y, this will result in divide by zero (for y=0 or z=0), or 1 (for any other y,z).

Comment: @dash yeah this works just fine (maybe I used bad implementation) but I want to append the bar by 1 when i'm inside the loop and it does just that